# Передача объекта в поток

Tags: python, многопоточность, сигналы-слоты, qthread, pyqt6

Задача состоит в том, чтобы передать из класса "кастомного" объекта типа `QWidget`, в другой поток его экземпляр и в другом потоке добавить, например на его `layout` `QLabel`.

Проблема возникает в следующем: в поток вроде бы передается ссылка на экземпляр объекта, но при попытке создать и разместить `QLabel` на его `layout` - нечего не происходит, либо виснет поток основной для отрисовки *GUI*, либо просто завершается приложение.

Как правильно реализовать данный метод?

Кастомный класс, типа `QWidget`:

```
class RigControl(QWidget):
    mainWidget: QWidget
    mainBoxLayout: QBoxLayout
    request = None
    rigsInfo = None
    thread = None
    worker = None

    def __init__(self, parentWidget=None):
        super(RigControl, self).__init__(parentWidget)
        self.mainWidget = QWidget(parentWidget)
        self.mainBoxLayout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.Direction.TopToBottom, self.mainWidget)
        self.thread = Worker(rc=self)
        self.thread.start()
```

Поток:

```
class Worker(QThread):
    layout: RigControl
    label: QLabel

    def __init__(self, rc, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.rc = rc

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.label = QLabel()
            self.label.setText("test QLabel")
            self.layout.mainBoxLayout.addWidget(self.label)
            print('threading...')
            QThread.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительных потоках. С виджетами работаем только в основном потоке.

Взаимосвязь между потоками осуществляется посредством сигналов и слотов.

[**Signals & Slots**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Сигналы и слоты используются для связи между объектами. Механизм сигналов и слотов является центральной особенностью Qt и, вероятно, той частью, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими фреймворками.

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Worker(QThread):
# ???    layout: RigControl
# ???    label: QLabel
    signalWorker = pyqtSignal(str)                                     # !!! +++

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
# ???        self.rc = rc

    def run(self):
        while True:
# ???            self.label = QLabel()
# ???            self.label.setText("test QLabel")
# ???            self.layout.mainBoxLayout.addWidget(self.label)

            # тут какая-то ваша тяжелая задача
            text = ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12))
            
            self.signalWorker.emit(text)                               # !!! +++
            self.msleep(1000)
            print('threading...')


class RigControl(QWidget):
    ''' ??? 
    mainWidget: QWidget
    mainBoxLayout: QBoxLayout
    request = None
    rigsInfo = None
    thread = None
    worker = None
    ''' 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RigControl, self).__init__(parent)

        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        
# ???         self.mainWidget = QWidget(parentWidget)
#        self.mainBoxLayout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.Direction.TopToBottom, self.mainWidget)
        self.mainBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)

        self.thread = Worker()
        self.thread.signalWorker.connect(self.update_text)            # !!! +++
        self.thread.start()

    def update_text(self, text):                                      # !!! +++
        self.textBrowser.append(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RigControl()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но, как оказалось, можно взаимодействовать через 'QTimer', но, к сожалению, нельзя передавать параметры в поток, который создает QTimer

Comment: @Duracell пожалуйста. Нельзя взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительных потоках. С виджетами работаем только в основном потоке. Передавать параметры между потоками можно посредством сигналов и слотов. Если вы самостоятельно решили свою проблему, опубликуйте ваше решение как ответ. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: не думаю что мой ответ является панацеей, скорее костылями, но и ваш ответ не совсем мне подходит